# What is the Cassandra setting for coordinator timeouts for schema change queries?

Tags: cassandra, query-timeout

In my testing, I've found that the [`write_request_timeout_in_ms`](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__write_request_timeout_in_ms) setting does not have any bearing on the timeouts for `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statements in CQL. For instance, I have it set to 10000ms but I've found that some `CREATE TABLE` statements can take around 12 seconds to complete. So what's the correct setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a Datastax representative, the setting which affects schema changes is [`request_timeout_in_ms`](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__request_timeout_in_ms).

It should be noted that these timeout settings are not hard timeouts from the time your client application connects to the coordinator node. If the connection is lost, then the timeout counter restarts. Hence why I was seeing some CREATE TABLE commands taking 12 seconds even though I had `request_timeout_in_ms` set to 10000ms.

Comment: @John I'm actually going to wait until I get more clarification from them because I'm not sure they're right. I posted this then quickly realized their answer didn't make sense.